# coroutines and parallelism in c++

Tags: c++, boost, c++-coroutine

It seems to me that coroutines are great for local interactions between a caller and a callee but I am having trouble to understand how they are gonna replace fibers. Consider the example below: I would like to control a level of parallelism to balance my cpu vs disk I/O latency, therefore I spawn multiple producer fibers and a single consumer fiber.

Is it possible to implement something similar using coroutines? Don't we need some sort of scheduler to be able to juggle between our asynchronous processes?

```
using namespace boost;
void read_lines_fiber(const string& fname, fibers::buffered_channel<string>& chan) {
  my_fiber_file f(fname, 'r');  // fiber friendly, suspends on IO read.
  for (string s : f) {
     chan.push(std::move(s));
  }
}

void consume_lines(fibers::buffered_channel<string>& chan) {
  string line;
  while (true) {
    channel_op_status st = chan.pop(line);
    if (st == channel_op_status::closed)
      break;
    // ... use line....
  }
}

void orchestrator(const vector<string>& filenames) {
 fibers::buffered_channel<string> chan;
 fibers::fiber consumer(&consume_lines, std::ref(chan));
 std::vector<fibers::fiber> producer_handles; 

 // Launch all the producer fibers. 
 // We might want to limit number of concurrent fibers using fiber friendly semaphore.
 for (const auto& s : filenames) {
   producer_handles.emplace_back(&read_lines_fiber, std::ref(chan));
 }
 for (auto& fb : producer_handles) {
   fb.join();
 }
 chan.close();
 consumer.join();
}
```